# jQuery ajax request and images loading

Tags: jquery

I have following ajax call:

```
$("#container").html("loading...");

$.ajax({
   url: "somedoc.php",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(response){
      if(response != ''){   
        $("#container").html(response);
      }                 
   }
});
```

Response look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="big_size_image_1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="big_size_image_2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="big_size_image_3.jpg" alt="" /></li> 
</ul>
```

Ajax call finishes up before all images are downloaded to the user. So 
is it possible to use load function here and show loading text while 
not all images are loaded ?

Your help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach a load event to the images, see if this works for you:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "somedoc.php",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(response){
      if(response != ''){
        var $imgs = $("#container").html(response)
                       .find("img") //find the appended images
                       .hide(), //hide them
            imgAmount = $imgs.length, 
            imgCounter = 0;

        //Here you should show your loading text

        $imgs.on("load", function(){
          imgCounter++;
          if(imgCounter === imgAmount) {

            //Here you should hide your loading text

            $imgs.fadeIn(); //show the images when they're loaded
          }
        });
      }                 
   }
});
```

Comment: The approach @Royi Namir took decrementing the amount to zero it's a good idea if you don't want to test the length

Answer (score 2):

yeah
if you know how many images ou should get ( you can count the Li's).

`#myWrapperelement` = the element to which you inject the response.

on the success: function :

```
   $("#MyloadingLabel").show()

      var  num=$("ul li").length;

                $("#myWrapperelement").on('load',"img ",function (){
                num--;
                if (num==0) $("#MyloadingLabel").hide();
            });
```