# Get the status of an image url before inserting into the dom

Tags: javascript

I have written a small JavaScript method that draws images to the DOM from a list of image urls from an S3 Bucket. In some instances these images can have broken urls. I have been searching for a the best way to test the status of these image urls with JavaScript before drawing them to the DOM. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add the code snippet you are using its important.

Comment: If you mean broken because of a bad url, you could use regex to test for it. If not, I'm afraid you'll have to make an ajax request for every url and read the status from there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278172/jquery-ajax-request-and-images-loading

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could either AJAX the image and check for a 404 before you add it, or handle the image's onError:

`<img src="image.png" onerror="hideImage(this);"/>`

Then retrospectively remove the image from the dom in the `hideImage` function.

Edit: to move away from inline attributes, you could also use this on document load:

`$("img").error(function () { $(this).remove(); }`